# Удаление бинарного дерева

Tags: c++, алгоритм, структуры, список, бинарное-дерево

Имеются функции:

```
struct Tree {
    int key;
    string inf;
    Tree *left;
    Tree *right;
};
    void deleteTree(Tree *&tree) {
        if (tree != NULL) {
            deleteTree(tree->left);
            deleteTree(tree->right);
            delete tree;
        }
    }
    void showTree(Tree *tree, int level) {
        string str;
        if (tree != NULL) {
            showTree(tree->right, level+1);
            for (int i = 0; i < level; i++) {
                str += "    ";
            }
            cout << str << tree->inf << " " << tree->key << endl;
            showTree(tree->left, level+1);
        }
    }
```

Задача - удаление созданного списка в виде бинарного дерева. Однако после удаления при просмотре выдает следующую ошибку: Вызвано исключение: нарушение доступа для чтения.

```
tree было 0xDDDDDDDD.
```

И указывает на строку

```
showTree(tree->right, level+1);
```

В чем ошибка и как исправить?

Comment: Что это у вас за магическая передача аргумента в функцию deleteTree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Следует обNULLить указатель после удаления дерева. Ну или лучше nullptr все таки, согласно ++11. Вы то проверяете указатель на != NULL,  а в Си значение указателя по умолчанию это мусор, который не NULL